# Holding a generic type's instance - C++

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I have a `tree_node` class and a `tree` class.

```
template<typename T>
class tree_node
{
public:
   tree_node(const std::string& key_, const T& value_) 
        : key(key_), value(value_)
   {
   }
private:
   T value;
   std::string key;
};

template<typename T>
class tree
{
public:
   tree() : root(new tree_node<T>("", ???)) { }
private:
   tree_node<T>* root;
};
```

`tree_node` expects an instance of `T` when creating. How can I pass it in the `???` place? I can say `T()`, but it will work only if `T` has a parameterless constructor. I can't have a parameterless constructor for `tree_node` as it won't compile if `T` doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

I am looking for a way to design `tree_node` which can hold all types correctly including pointer types.

**Edit**

After trying various methods, I found that `boost::optional` is helpful in this case. I can make the `T value` into `boost::optional<T> value`. This will solve the empty constructor issue. So I can have another constructor overload of `tree_node` which just takes a `key`. This can be used by the root node. Is this the correct way to go?

Thanks..

Comment: Default constructor sets root to NULL instead?

Comment: simply don't? couldn't you just create the root when it's necessary to do so?

Comment: @UncleBens: root should be available all the time so that I can append the child elements. Problem is, root doesn't really hold any value. @roe: even if I do creation of root lazily, what value will I pass?

Comment: I believe you should rethink your container invariants. I am quite sure that having a dummy root node will not really help anywhere, not in the implementation not in time or memory requirements. Why, if the tree is initially empty, should it have a node?

Comment: You need to consider whether any simplification of always having a root overweighs the complexity of having to work around the empty constructor issue.

Answer (score 4):

Init root value should be zero. If you push new node you obviously know value.

```
template<typename T> 
class tree 
{ 
public: 
   tree() : root(0) { } 
   void push (const std::string& key, const T & t) {
      if (root == 0) {
        root = new tree_node<T>(key, t);
      } else {
         // Make complex tree
      }
   }
private: 
   tree_node<T>* root; 
};
```

**Add**

If you use suffix tree you should make two types of vertices:

```
enum NodeType { EMPTY_NODE, VALUE_NODE };

class base_tree_node 
{ 
public: 
   base_tree_node() :parent(0), left(0), right(0) {}

   virtual NodeType gettype() = 0;

protected: 
   base_tree_node* parent;
   base_tree_node* left;
   base_tree_node* right;
}; 

class empty_tree_node : base_tree_node
{
   virtual NodeType gettype()  { return EMPTY_NODE; }
}

template<typename T> 
class tree_node : base_tree_node 
{ 
public: 
   tree_node(const std::string& key_, const T& value_)  
        : key(key_), value(value_) 
   { 
   } 

   virtual NodeType gettype()  { return VALUE_NODE; }

private: 
   T value; 
   std::string key; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But in my case, root should hold just empty value. All item added will append to this root or append to other children of this root.

Comment: @Appu: why? In general, all tree nodes should contain actual data, and the root pointer (not root node) should point to the top of the hierarchy. Assuming a binary tree, if the root node is empty, where will contents be added, left? right? That does not make any sense.

Comment: Well, what I am making is a `trie` (suffix tree). In that, root will be empty.

Comment: @Appu: Then use `T * pvalue` instead of `T value` inside `tree_node`.

Comment: @Alexy:Thanks for adding new information. It looks helpful. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
tree( const T & t ) : root(new tree_node<T>("", t )) { }
```

Comment: Well, so caller has to do `foo dummy(..); tree<foo> t(dummy)` ?

Comment: @Appu If you're constraining the tree to always have at least one node with a value, then passing the value into the tree's constructor makes sense.

Comment: @Appu No - tree <foo> t( foo( .. ) );

Comment: `explicit tree( const T& t = T() ) : ...` might be a slight improvement.

Comment: Even if that node is always going to be "unused"? I'd think either you don't have unused nodes, or you'll indeed need a way not to construct an object there (e.g `std::vector` does manage to have reserved memory with no objects constructed - reserve call doesn't ask you to supply a dummy object).

Answer (score 0):

I have once done a linked list (just for fun) which needed a sentinel node not meant to hold any data, and I had the following structure:

```
struct BaseNode
{
    BaseNode* next;
    BaseNode(BaseNode* next): next(next) {}
};

template <class T>
struct Node: public BaseNode
{
    T data;
    Node(const T& data, BaseNode* next): BaseNode(next), data(data) {}
};

template <class T>
struct List
{
    BaseNode* head;
    List(): head(new BaseNode(0)) {}
    void add(const T& value)
    {
        Node<T>* new_node = new Node<T>(value, head->next);
        head->next = new_node;
    }
    T& get_first()
    {
        assert(head->next);
        return static_cast<Node<T>*>(head->next)->data;
    }
    //...
};
```

The class itself must make sure it gets necessary casts right and doesn't try to cast head or root itself to `Node<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

A tree node should have (or be) a collection of child nodes. A tree should have (or be) a collection of root nodes. Both those collections should be the same type. Very simply:

```
template <class T>
class NodeCollection
{
    std::vector<Node<T> *> nodes;

public:
    // any operations on collection of nodes
    // copy ctor and destructor a must!
};

template <class T>
class Node : public NodeCollection<T> 
{
    T value;

public:
    // ctor
    // access to value
};

template <class T>
class Tree : public NodeCollection<T> 
{
public:
    // ctor
};
```

This way the shared definition of `Tree` and `Node` is actually in `NodeCollection`, and so `Tree` doesn't need to carry a dummy value.