# Using boost::optional with constant types - C++

Tags: c++, templates, boost, const-correctness

I have a container class which uses `boost::optional` to hold the value. Here is the code looks like,

```
template<typename T>
struct traits
{
    typedef T  value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
};

template<typename T>
struct traits<const T>
{
    typedef const T  value_type;
    typedef const T& reference;
};

template<typename T>
struct traits<T*>
{
    typedef T* value_type;
    typedef T* reference;
};

template<typename T>
struct traits<const T*>
{
    typedef const T* value_type;
    typedef const T* reference;
};

template<typename T>
class container
{
public:

    typedef typename traits<T>::reference reference;
    typedef typename traits<T>::value_type value_type;

    container() {}

    void set(reference value) {
        op.reset(value);
    }

    reference get() const {
        return boost::get(op);
    }

private:
    boost::optional<value_type> op;
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    container<const foo> c;
    c.set(f);
    return 0;
}
```

It works well for other types except `const`. I am getting error when I use `const` types (`const foo*` works fine).

1. Is `boost::optional` supports constant types? If no, how can I work around this issue?
2. Is there a ready made traits implementation available which I can use rather than defining my own traits?

Any help would be great!

Comment: `const foo*` is of course not a const type. `foo* const` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with `boost::optional`, but with the logic of what you're trying to do. First you create a container of const, and then you try to modify what's contained. I would be surprised if that worked.

I think you should probably do what standard containers (like `vector`) do and forbid non-copyable template arguments.

Otherwise you'll have to live with the fact that your `set` method won't work when `T` is non-copyable, and provide a constructor that performs the initialization:

```
class container
{
public:

    container(reference init_value) : op(init_value) {}

};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    container<const foo> c(f);  // OK
    //   c.set(f);  NO
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Well i agree with your criticism on his code. I deleted my answer because i found i'm teaching dangerous practice in it. If the purpose of the container is what we both suspect, then i agree with your answer.

Comment: @Manuel: I am not really experimenting to add different levels of indirection. I got lost in the templates world. I have a tree_node which holds a value as a key. Value will be stored in `optional`. Whenever I try the node with a different type, it is giving errors and can't make it work for all types.

Comment: @Appu - what you're doing is tricky, it's normal that you get into trouble if you don't have a lot of experience with C++. I'm curious, what makes you think you need to use `optional`?

Comment: @Manuel: Please take a look at my other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274817/holding-a-generic-types-instance-c . I have explained why I started using optional.

Comment: @Appu - Sounds like a reasonable application of `boost::optional`. My advice is that you forget about all this traits madness, if the user wants to store pointers then the `reference` type should be a reference to a pointer, there's nothing wrong with that. That's the way STL containers work, by the way

Comment: @Manuel: Let me try it. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
struct traits
{
    typedef T  value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
};

template<typename T>
struct traits<const T>
{
    typedef const T  value_type;
    typedef const T& reference;
};
```

Isn't the `const` specialization completely pointless? Without the specialization, `traits<const int>` will have `const int` as the `value_type` and `const int&` as the `reference`, which is exactly what you tried to achieve with the `const` specialization, right?